# How to install the latest version of codelite?

Tags: 14.04

How to install the latest version of **Codelite?**
OS:*Ubuntu 14.04.02 64 bit.*

Comment: http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/Repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DOWNLOAD**

1. Add CodeLite public key to avoid warnings from apt/aptitude

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
   ```
2. Add appropriate repository. As you mentioned you use ***Ubuntu 14.04.02- Trusty Tahr***

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe'
   ```
3. Now you need to update your repositories

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

**INSTALL**

1. Install Codelite

   ```
   sudo apt-get install codelite wxcrafter
   ```