# Codelite installation unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I would like to update the repository of my system

> ```
> holger@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/os-release
> NAME="Ubuntu"
> VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
> holger@ubuntu:~$ uname -m
> i686
> ```

with a newer codelite version (9.1), as the offical ubuntu repository contains an old one (2.8). I followed these instructions: [How to install the latest version of codelite?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593592/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-codelite/593604)

But I see this dependency error:

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   codelite : Depends: liblldb-3.6 but it is not installable
>           Recommends: lldb (>= 3.4) but it is not installable
>           Recommends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

The installed version is:

> ```
> liblldb-3.9/trusty-security,now 1:3.9.1-4ubuntu3~14.04.2 i386 [installed]
> ```

I appreciate any ideas how to fix it.

**Edit:**
By checking on the codelite dependencies, I see the following:

> ```
> holger@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep codelite
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 2:1.2.99) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Build-dependencies for codelite could not be satisfied.
> ```

libgtk2.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev and other libs. When I try to install libglib2.0-dev, I get the following error:

```
> holger@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev Reading package
> lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information...
> Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
> been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
> resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libglib2.0-dev :
> Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.0-2) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to $
>                   Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.40.0-2) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is t$
>                   Depends: libpcre3-dev (>= 1:8.31) but it is not going to be i$ E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.
```

So the dependend libs are on my system, they just differ in the minor release number. As I understand it I need version 2.40.0-2 for libglib2.0-0 but have version 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 installed.

What repo can I get these packages from? The standard repo only allows to install this version:

```
> holger@ubuntu:~$ apt search libglib2.0
> ...  
> libglib2.0-dev/trusty
> 2.40.0-2 i386   Development files for the GLib library
```

Please let me know, what am I missing here?

Comment: 3.6 is not 3.9.  Why don't you just upgrade to 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is install it from its repository. From the website TipsUbuntu, it has instructions for the latest version 9.2 [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/09/19/install-codelite-ide-9-2-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/).

1. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ trusty universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/codelite.list'` <- Add the repository.
2. `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc` <- Setup the key trust.
3. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install codelite wxcrafter` <- Install!
4. If it gives you any dependency issues, you can fix them with `sudo apt-get install -f`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, xR34P3Rx, but same behavior. I had already added the codelite repo to /etc/apt/sources.list. Deleted it, tried your instructions, same dependency error. I will dig a little deeper into the dependencies and will share my observations.